# TableView removes cells when I ask it to add more cells when scrolled to the bottom. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I have a table view that is populating itself from an array that currently contains 45 items. The goal is for it to initially show 20, and to incrementally display 20 more items when the user scrolls to the bottom of the table view.

Here is the method that populates the cells with information.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[listings objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"listingName"];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the method that determines the length of the table view:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (listings.count < 20){
        return listings.count;
    }
    return tableViewSize; 
}
```

`tableViewSize` is an instance variable that I instantiate with a value of 20. I use the following method to increment it by 20 whenever the user scrolls to the bottom:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == (listings.count - 1)){
        tableViewSize += 20;
        if(tableViewSize > listings.count){
            tableViewSize = listings.count; 
        }
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

The problem is very odd. When I include the latter method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, the table view only shows one cell (I cannot tell which object in the array this is because at the moment all of the object are the same. If needed, I can find out). If I comment out the latter method, then the table view properly displays 20 cells.

Does anyone know why this method is causing the table view to behave this way?

Comment: Okay, this removed the problem, the table view is now loading all 20 cells, however now it's not incrementing by 20 when I scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made yourself an infinite loop.

Each time a cell will be displayed you call `reloadData`. After each `reloadData` the tableView is reloaded and all cells will be displayed again. Which will again call reloadData. After that the first cell is displayed again. And so on.

Try to put the call to reloadData into the if that increases the number of items in the tableView.

Like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == (listings.count - 1)){
        tableViewSize += 20;
        if(tableViewSize > listings.count){
            tableViewSize = listings.count; 
        }
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

---

For a better user experience I use a different way of reloading new cells. Right now your scroll stops when it reaches the last cell. So the user has to scroll a couple of times to see item 100. Something like this might work better because it keeps the momentum of the scroll:

```
// viewDidLoad
displayedCount = 20;
realCount = 200;   // according to your backing array



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return displayedCount;
}


- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height * 0.75) {
        // reload when the user scrolled to 75% of the current cells. This way you can keep the momentum of the scroll and the table does not stop. 
        displayedCount += 20;
        if (displayedCount > realCount) {
            displayedCount = realCount;
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it need to go inside the first if statement? rather than the nested one?

Comment: indeed. my mistake. For a better user experience I would recommend another way to do the parsing. I'll add it in a minute

Comment: i need help regarding the same issue, i have a JSON response of image and it has 193 data as of now it can be increased in future so currently i want to display only 20 cells at one time and when user reaches at 20th cells and scrolls i want to show another 20 cells below so that image loading will be faster . i want like facebook pagination, i donot want to add pagecount to increment and fetch the value when i call delegate methods.thnks in advance... this is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187395/how-to-show-cells-based-on-increment-of-array-in-tableview-swift-3

Comment: @MatthiasBauch could u help me

Answer (score 0):

What I think is happening is that the tableview in constantly reloading because some of the logic is incorrect. Modify willDisplayCell like so and see if that fixes the problem:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == (tableViewSize - 1) && listings.count > tableViewSize) {
        tableViewSize += 20;
        if(tableViewSize > listings.count){
            tableViewSize = listings.count; 
        }
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```